# How can you access the value of a cell in different cell of the same row in Angular Material Data-Table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a Angular Material Data Table with four columns. The last cell of every row is a button with an on-click function attached to it. I want to use the value of my first cell ("Name") as a parameter in the function that is attached to the button in the corresponding last cell. How can this be accomplished?

At the moment restart() has no parameters yet but I would like to add one to pass it on to my api.

table.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { PowershellService } from 'src/app/services/powershell.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
    import { powershell } from 'src/app/models/powershell.model';
    import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-apps-table',
      templateUrl: './apps-table.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./apps-table.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppsTableComponent implements OnInit {
    
      dataSource = new PowerShellDataSource(this.powershellService);
      displayedColumns = ['Name', 'Description', 'Status', 'options'];
    
      constructor(private powershellService: PowershellService,
        private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      
      restart() {
        this.powershellService.getRestart()
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.snackBar.open(data, 'Close', {
              duration: 4000,
              panelClass: ['snackbar']
            });
          },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error);
              this.snackBar.open(error, 'Close', {
                duration: 4000,
                panelClass: ['snackbar']
              });
            });
            
      }
    
    }
    
    
    export class PowerShellDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    
      constructor(private powershellService: PowershellService) {
        super();
      }
    
      connect(): Observable<powershell[]> {
        return this.powershellService.getPowershellApps();
      }
    
      disconnect() { };
}
```

table.component.html

```
    <div>
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z3">
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">{{powershell.Name}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Description">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">{{powershell.Description}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</mat-header-cell>
                <ng-container *matCellDef="let powershell">
                    <mat-cell [ngSwitch]="powershell.Status">
                        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Running'">
                            <mat-chip-list>
                                <mat-chip class="running" selected>Running</mat-chip>
                            </mat-chip-list>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'Stopped'">
                            <mat-chip-list>
                                <mat-chip class="stopped" selected>Stopped</mat-chip>
                            </mat-chip-list>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                            <mat-chip-list>
                                <mat-chip>{{powershell.Status}}</mat-chip>
                            </mat-chip-list>
                        </ng-container>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
    
            <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Options</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let powershell">
                    <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
                        <mat-icon>desktop_mac</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
    
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" class="table-row"></mat-row>
    
        </mat-table>
    </div>

<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="restart()">Restart</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: It would be easier to have a look at the problem if you provided a
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
You can set one up over at [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: Do you mean restart() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in data to a menu can be done like this:

change this:

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
```

to this: (with `matMenuTriggerData` we pass the context data)

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{ps: powershell}>
```

then change your `mat-menu` to this:

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-ps="ps">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="restart(ps)">Restart</button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

note the `matMenuContent` where you can use the `let-` template input variable.

on TS side you can access the whole row (powershell) fields (any cell):

```
  restart(powershell) {
    alert('restart: ' + JSON.stringify(powershell));
  }
```

`console.log(powershell.Name);`

Check the relevant Angular Material docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#passing-in-data-to-a-menu)

and

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtax4f?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Comment: awesome. works like a charm. I only changed  restart(powershell) to restart(powershell: any) in the ts since it was throwing a "implicitly has an 'any' type" error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="restart(powershell.Name)">Restart</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Like this way you can try

Comment: powershell.Name can not be accessed outside of <mat-cell> as far as I know.

Comment: From where do you get powershell